# The onmousemove event for addEventListener on canvas does not work

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events

Please I need your help. The onmousemove event for addEventListener  on canvas does not work!

For example the following code does not work:

```
canv.addEventListener("onmousemove", function(event){console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY,"page");});
```

but if we replace the `onmousemove` event by click event it works.

So please I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using addEventListener, drop the "on" part of the event name.  So

```
canv.addEventListener("mousemove", function ...
```